# How would you express "sphere" or "world" in the Japanese language?

Tags: word-choice, suffixes

How would you express the concept of "sphere" or "world" in Japanese? For example, "Anglosphere" or "Indian speaking world". Is there a repeating pattern or suffix for this purpose, or are there just specific words for these terms?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The most common word and character associated for this kind of usage is [圏]{けん}.

Anglosphere would be [英語圏]{えいごけん}, and a common term to refer to the East Asian cultural sphere is [漢字文化圏]{かんじぶんかけん} which encompasses China, Japan, Korea and Vietnam.

Answer (score 7):

There is also the word [分野]{ぶん・や} that means field/realm/sphere.

Some examples

> - 研究分野　→　field of research
> - 彼は物理学の分野でよく知られている　→　He is well-known in the field of physics
> - 彼は彫刻の分野では第一人者だ　→　He is second to none in the world of sculpture.

Also the suffix 〜[界]{かい}.

> - 政界　→　the political world
> - 芸能界　→　the entertainment world; show businesses
> - 業界　→　the business world

---

*Examples taken from プログレッシブ英和・和英中辞典 and ウィズダム英和辞典.*

Answer (score 3):

There's 圏 as in e.g. [漢字文化圏（かんじぶんかけん）](https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E6%BC%A2%E5%AD%97%E6%96%87%E5%8C%96%E5%9C%8F) and [英語圏（えいごけん）](https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E8%8B%B1%E8%AA%9E%E5%9C%8F).